# migration of sharepoint and TFS to a new domain - cannot access my site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We migrated our Sharepoint 2010 Farm to a new domain. One of the site collections was set up as a TFS Home site and we also migrated our TFS server.

We added the new domain account administrator account and reset all services to use the new account.

The trouble we find when trying to access the site now, is below.  Also, via TFS team explorer we can no longer see the Documents libraries that once were hooked up.

Any ideas?

--------------- error trying to access the home page of the TFS template site collection -------------

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties() +134
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs() +44
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext) +329
   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalAvailable() +44
   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.EnsureMySiteUrls() +60
   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalMySiteUrlAvailable() +15
   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427

Answer (score 0):

Someone had modified the Team Project Settings -> Portal Settings in Team Explorer to point to a different site collection.  Pointing it back to the original one fixed the TFS integration.

The Permissions were causing the other errors. We had to re-add all the new domain accounts to the right permission groups. That and then we re-synch'ed UserProfile Service seems to have gotten us back to great.